# Limit number of records in aerospike select query

Tags: database, aerospike

I am trying to query using **aql (Aerospike Query Language) in aerospike set**.
Suppose there are 1000 records and I want to read any 10 records. Usually I would query something like :

```
select * from test.demo limit 10;
```

How do I query the same using **aql** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment you cannot do that in aql, but you can use the BETWEEN predicate to define a range to the query.

When you use the C-client (or one of the language clients that wrap around it) a scan ([as_scan_foreach](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/dc/dd6/group__scan__operations.html#gabb9ab24e0471c7f5f285f4e72c93bba9)) can be limited by setting [the percentage](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/db/d31/as__scan_8h_source.html#l00297) field of the [as_scan](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d1/dc3/structas__scan.html) struct.

Comment: This is such a basic requirement, 4 years later they still don't have this in their AQL CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of 'scan' in Java.

```
    **this.client.scanAll(scanPolicy, "test", "demo", new ScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void scanCallback(Key key, Record record) throws AerospikeException {
            System.out.println("Record: " + record);

        }
    });**
```

That there is no order implied in a 'scan', records are returned to your application in the order they are received from the nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Hmm... I think because of this randomness Aerospike will not be a fit for pagination?